# Emailing contact form information

Tags: php, forms, email

When a customer fills out my for, it sends it in an email to my email address. The email contains all of the information from the form except for where the contact heard about the website. In the form this option is a drop down menu. Any advise would be great.

This is the form:

```
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Full Name:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row-->


<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Email Address:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="emailaddress" class="detail" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" />
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row-->

    <br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Your Message:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row--> 

<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Select your gender:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">   
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"  id="gender_male" CHECKED/>
<label for="gender_male"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender_female" />
<label for="gender_female" />Female
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row--> 




<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Please select your age:</div>
  <!--End of Lable-->
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="range1" value="18-25" CHECKED />
  18-25 
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="range2" value="26-33" />26-33 
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="range3" value="24-40" />34-40 
  <input type="radio" name="age" id="range4" value="40+" />40+<br />
 </div><!--Row-->

  <br />
  <div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Select 3 products that you are interested in hearing about:</div> 
<!--End of Lable-->
<input type="checkbox" name="Interested[]" id="protien" value="protien" />Protien
<input type="checkbox" name="Interested[]" id="creatine" value="creatine" />Creatine<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Interested[]"  id="bcaa" value="bcaa" />BCAA
<input type="checkbox" name="Interested[]" id="power drinks" value="powerdrinks" />Power Drinks<br />
</div><!--Row-->





<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Where did you hear about us?</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<select>
<option value="Google" selected="selected" name="Google" id="heard"  /> Google Search
<option value="WordOfMouth" name="heard" id="WordOfMouth" /> Word of mouth 
<option value="Newspaper" name="heard" id="Neawspaper" /> Newspaper
<option value="Magazine" name="heard" id="Magazine" /> Magazine
</select>
</div><!--Row-->



<br />
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" id="send" Name="send" value="Send" />
</div><!--End of submit-->

<div class="Clear">
<input type="reset" id="clear" Name="Clear" value="Clear" />
</div>





</form>
```

This is the reply.php action:

```
$name = $_POST["fullname"];
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$comments = $_POST["comment"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$Interested = $_POST['Interested'];
$heard = $_POST["heard"];


$message = "New Email for a customer" .



         "\r\nName of the contact" .
         "\r\n-". $name .
         "\r\nEmail address of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$email .
         "\r\nThe comment that the contact has made" . 
         "\r\n-".$comments .
         "\r\nThe gender of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$gender .
         "\r\nThe age range of the contact" . 
         "\r\n-".$age .
         "\r\nThe products that the customer is interested in" . 
         "\r\n-".implode(", " ,$Interested).
         "\r\nWhere the contact heard of Shredded Nutrition"  .
         "\r\n-".$Heard . 
         "\r\n-" .
  $headers =  "From: " . $email;


mail("kieran@localhost",$subject,$message,$headers);
$subjectReply = 'Thank you for your contact..';
$messageReply = 'You will soon receive an answer';
$headers = 'From: admin@shreddednutrition';

mail($email, $subjectReply, $messageReply, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: could be as simple as you assigned the select value to `$heard` but used `$Heard` in the `$message` variable.

Comment: Thanks this was a mistake when I was trying to sort it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select should be named `heard`

I.e:

```
<select name="heard">
```

and remove the `name="heard"` from your options. `value` will take care of that.

---

```
<select name="heard">
<option value="Google" selected="selected" id="heard"  /> Google Search
<option value="WordOfMouth" id="WordOfMouth" /> Word of mouth 
<option value="Newspaper" id="Neawspaper" /> Newspaper
<option value="Magazine" id="Magazine" /> Magazine
</select>
```

Also, change `.$Heard` to `.$heard` since you're using `$heard = $_POST["heard"];`

More specifically:

`"\r\n-".$Heard .` to `"\r\n-".$heard .`

POST variables are case-sensitive. Not doing so, you will not see the choice in the Email.

Comment: This is the most correct answer, removing `name=""` from the <option> tags. But make sure you also remove `name="Google"` from the first `<option>`

Comment: Thank you! Got it sorted now.

Comment: Oh Lordy, thank Richard, I missed that one. Thanks for the edit @RichardChristensen

Comment: I don't know why, I think other editors might have rejected your edit. But I changed it now. Personally, I would have approved it. @RichardChristensen cheers

Comment: @Kie21 Just a quick note about a typo in `id="Neawspaper"` which should read as `id="Newspaper"` should that give you a problem.

Comment: Thanks, glad you pointed that our because I hadn't seen it haha

Answer (score 0):

Your select should have the *name* of heard, not the options inside. The select is what is actually sent back to the application, the options are more the values that the user is allowed to select. Add the below, but remove the id of heard off of the top option you have presently.

```
<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Where did you hear about us?</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<select name="heard">
<option value="Google" selected="selected" name="Google"> Google Search</option>
<option value="WordOfMouth" id="WordOfMouth"> Word of mouth </option>
<option value="Newspaper" id="Neawspaper"> Newspaper</option>
<option value="Magazine" id="Magazine"> Magazine</option>
</select>
</div><!--Row-->
```

Should resolve it.

Comment: @Dagon you're right. My bad, end of the day and all that.

Comment: When submitting a form the `value=""` attribute is passed to the server, not the `id=""` attribute.

Comment: @RichardChristensen The value is passed on as the value, but the name is passed as the index of the $_GET, $_POST, etc. Without having the name defined, there was no way to even get to the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Got it sorted